# How can I use tmux for copying if I can't access the system clipboard?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, tmux

I'm testing out using vim with tmux. One thing that I could do with vim with a split window is yank text from one buffer and paste it into the other. This no longer works when I have vim buffers in different panes. Any idea how to get this working?

I'm working on Mac Terminal (El Capitan) over SSH into a Linux box.

**UPDATE** And it does not look like my version of vim has the `+clipboard` feature compiled into it.

**NOTE** This is not a duplicate question as this is specifically about using tmux with vim. I want to be able to issue a `yy` command like I usually do in one vim pane in tmux and `p` it into another vim pane in tmux.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `tmux`, you simply want to be able to yank/paste between two different instances of `vim`, right?

Comment: +clipboard is for graphical vim; it won't be relevant for running vim in a terminal. Sounds like you probably either want to copy/paste using the terminal itself, or try having your console session interface with OSX directly. There's probably a way to use pbpaste and pbcopy to do what you want if you set up a key binding; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130968/how-can-i-copy-the-output-of-a-command-directly-into-my-clipboard and http://superuser.com/questions/231130/unable-to-use-pbcopy-while-in-tmux-session/413233#413233 (I'd try myself, but I don't have an OSX box).

Comment: @pfnuesel, yes, I want to do a `yy` command in one pane and `p` into another pane. I can't use the system clipboard because my non-gui version of vim does not have the clipboard compiled into it. I've tried many of the various solutions recommended but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I wonder if this is the reason why I'm having trouble: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201341

Comment: It's cumbersome, but without access to the system clipboard, I think a shared file is the simplest way.

Comment: `tmux` has a "copy mode", but it's a bit awkward to use. It also has the `:set-buffer` and `:paste-buffer` commands, as well as some other related commands (see the `BUFFERS` section in `tmux(1)`). Not entirely sure how to run this from Vim (maybe something with `:bind-key -n yy ...`?) It also has the `Ms` terminfo extension to interface with the clipboard (with `:set-clipboard`).

Answer (score 2):

Use [fakeclip.vim](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22617497/2350060) for details.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'd like to note that the implication that you cannot use the system clipboard from terminal Vim is false. I use it all the time. (This implication isn't in your question, but it is in the comments.) So if I were in your situation, I would simply install a different Vim package that *does* include the `+clipboard` feature.

That said, here's a proof of concept which uses a tmux buffer and the `system()` function to provide (just) the functionality you asked for:

```
nnoremap <silent> yy yy:call system('tmux set-buffer -b vim ' . shellescape(@"))<CR>
nnoremap <silent> p :let @" = system('tmux show-buffer -b vim')<cr>p$x
```

These mappings use the standard `yy` and `p` commands to perform the actual yank and put, but include system calls to save the contents of the unnamed register in a tmux buffer after yanking and load the buffer contents back into the unnamed register before putting.

N.B. If I were using this in earnest, I would extend this and tidy it up a fair bit (for instance, with these mappings you can now *only* `p` things that you have previously yanked with `yy`: the easiest way around this is use `<leader>yy` and `<leader>p` as the triggers), but this shows the basic functionality.

Here's another version which instead uses tmux's `send-keys` to directly copy over the contents of the unnamed register when you yank, which in some ways is cleaner, and avoids the problem with the `p` mapping described above:

```
nnoremap <silent> yy yy:call system('tmux send-keys -t 1 ":let @\" = \"' . shellescape(@")[1:-2] . '\"' . "\r\"")<CR>
```

Currently this is losing the newline at the end of the yanked line: it could probably be tidied up not to do so.